# Listings for Tikz code?

Tags: listings, tikz-pgf

I am trying to quote (not compile!) LaTeX code (including TikZ code) within a LaTeX document.  The `verbatim` package works, but it doesn't wrap text and doesn't look very nice.  So I am trying to use the package `listings`, but am having problems:

It is giving me issues on the quoted code when I try to compile, when it should just be treating it like text!  I imagine this is because it is trying to color the syntax or something, but at this point that would be a bonus — I just want the code to look nice and wrap (and not compile within `\begin{lstlisting}`).

Also, it seems that the TikZ code that I use within a LaTeX document is also giving `listings` trouble.

```
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
language=TeX,                       
defaultdialect=empty,
basicstyle=\footnotesize,           
numbers=left,                           
numberstyle=\footnotesize,          
stepnumber=5,                           
numbersep=5pt,                      
backgroundcolor=\color{white},  
showspaces=false,                   
showstringspaces=false,             
showtabs=false,                     
frame=single,                   
tabsize=2,                  
captionpos=b,               
breaklines=true,                
breakatwhitespace=false,        
escapeinside={\%}{)}            
}


\begin{document}
The document begins.  A bunch of regular Latex code and TikZ pictures here.
\begin{lstlisting}

%Set domain, range, and scale of picture.
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:100,range=0:200,scale=0.7,thick]
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%Define linear parameters 
\def\inc{10}            %Total freight.
\def\pa{1}              %Price of x1.
\def\pb{1}              %Price of x2.
\def\panew{0.5}     %New price for x1.

% Define coordinates.
\coordinate (x2) at  (0,{\inc/\pb});
\coordinate (x1) at  ({\inc/\pa},0);
\coordinate (x1') at  ({\inc/\panew},0);

\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Note: I do not want the TikZ picture to render within `\begin{lstlisting}`, I just want to be able to show the code.  Same with the the LaTeX code within it.

Is there a better way to tackle this?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

You are explicitly requesting that everything from a `%` to the next `)` be executed as LaTeX code, removing the line `escapeinside={\%}{)}` fixes this.

Comment: @baha-kev: please don't forget to accept the question.